# VIM ( gvim ) where is the color-settings stored for gVIm on Linux Desktop?

Tags: linux, bash, text-editor, vim

I selected a color-scheme on newly installed g-vim

i can not locate any settings in

```
Gnome Configuration Editor ( gconftool-2 )
```

is there a file that where my color schemes and etc are stored?

Comment: You can also try the [Sublime Text](http://www.sublimetext.com/) and use the [Vintage mode](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/2/vintage.html). It's cool and makes you feel like vim.

Comment: Probably under `/usr/share/vim/vim73/colors` if you don't have any defined in your login folder. If you have personal ones set up in your login, they'd be under `~/.vim/colors`.

Comment: You should read [`:help usr_05.txt`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/usr_05.html#usr_05.txt) and [`:help usr_06.txt`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/usr_06.html#usr_06.txt). The first one covers vimrc and the second covers syntax highlighting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enable syntax highlighting:

```
echo "syntax on" >> ~/.gvimrc
```

Use default color scheme:

```
echo "colorscheme slate" >> ~/.gvimrc
```

Answer (score 1):

Colorschemes are located in these two places.

The system defined color schemes are located in `$VIM/colors`. You can find the value of `$VIM` by typing `:echo $VIM` in vim.

The user defined color schemes are located in `$HOME/.vim/colors` (This folder will not exist until you create it)

To use a colorsheme you should put `colorscheme <name>` in your vimrc (`$HOME/.vimrc`).

To find the names of all colorschemes that you can use you can type `:colorscheme <c-d>` (press control-d after a space)

gvim (and vim) do not store settings through gnome.